# Acessar valor dentro da tag do componente

Tags: angularjs, angular

No meu componente estou tentando pegar o valor dentro da tag deste mesmo componente para exibi-lo no html do mesmo, porém, este componente é o componente principal da minha aplicação, O que estou querendo é tipo isto:

```
<teste>Testando... 1... 2... 3...</teste>
```

E dentro do meu componente eu jogar o "Testando... 1... 2... 3..." para dentro de uma variável ou mostrá-lo no html do componente.

± igual ao slot do vue.js...

No meu index.html eu coloco:

```
<teste>Testando... 1... 2... 3...</teste>
```

E gostaria de pegar o texto no meu app.component.ts

Comment: Como você está comunicando com esse "componente"? via Controller, Directive...

Comment: Lucas, queria via component mesmo (app.component.ts). Alterei o enunciado, veja se melhorou.